# Does a localhost request connect to the network?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

This might be somewhat of a silly question but, does connecting to the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` actually initiate the network connection to the router and then comes back as a received signal or does it bypass the network altogether and just achieves the same effect by mimicking a network in software?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> …does connecting to the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` actually initiate the
> network connection to the router and then comes back as a received
> signal or does it bypass the network altogether and just achieves the
> same effect by mimicking a network in software?

When you connect to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` that is strictly a local connection on your local machine managed by the local OS. It never connects to an external router or device to achieve connectivity.

But when you say “…mimicking a network in software…” that is not exactly right. A system does not “mimick” a network when using `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`; networking functionality that would exist outside your OS system exists naturally as a part of the core OS on your system when using `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`.

The whole reason that `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` is considered a loopback connection is exactly that: A strictly local connection that feeds on itself but ultimately uses the same exact protocol and network structures a supposed “real” network does. A loopback connection is designed for testing and debugging—and sometimes local application needs—so it never “mimics” anything; it is what it is which is a network connection.

And for what it's worth, some software [such as Firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=159975) have deliberately used “acts as a server” processes that connect to an application created server reachable on `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` as part of it’s normal operations. And many RESTful API-based pieces of server software make use of local loopback to have a front-end layer of their core code talk back to a locally-based RESTful API for core operations.

Answer (score 1):

It bounces back to your machine, does not reach the external router, in other words, it does half of the journey in the OSI layer and returns.